# List Field field don't show a value

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

When I paste a value into a combo box, it is not displayed when I paste it on load. Although when inserting a value without passing an argument into the form, everything works. How to fix it?
The first picture shows the problem itself. The second shows that everything will work without passing an argument to the form! And in the drop-down list itself, everything is displayed

```
' Populating a list of values
If Not Me!PostField.RowSource = "" Then Me!PostField.RowSource = ""
   Me!PostField.ColumnCount = 2
   Me!PostField.ColumnWidths = "0; 25"
   Set QueryRecordset = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblPost.PostCode, tblPost.PostName FROM tblPost;")
   Do Until QueryRecordset.EOF
       Me!PostField.RowSource = Me!PostField.RowSource & QueryRecordset("PostCode").Value & ";" & QueryRecordset("PostName").Value & ";"
       QueryRecordset.MoveNext
   Loop
   QueryRecordset.Close

' Inserting user data
QueryObj = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qrsCurrentEmployeeInfo")
   QueryObj![EmployeeCode] = CInt(Me.OpenArgs)
   Set QueryRecordset = QueryObj.OpenRecordset
   Do Until QueryRecordset.EOF
       Me!Title.Caption = QueryRecordset("LastName").Value & " " & QueryRecordset("FirstName").Value & " " & QueryRecordset("MiddleName").Value & " (Ðåäàêòèðîâàíèå)"
       Me!LastNameField.Value = QueryRecordset("LastName").Value
       Me!FirstNameField.Value = QueryRecordset("FirstName").Value
       Me!MiddleNameField.Value = QueryRecordset("MiddleName").Value
       Me!SexField.Value = QueryRecordset("Pol").Value
       Me!IndividualTaxNumberField.Value = QueryRecordset("InduvialNumber").Value
       Me!SalaryField.Value = QueryRecordset("Salary").Value
       Me!CompanyField.Value = QueryRecordset("CompanyCode").Value
       Me!LegalAddressField.Value = QueryRecordset("LegalAddress").Value
       Me!ActualAddressField.Value = QueryRecordset("ActualAddress").Value
       Me!PhoneField.Value = QueryRecordset("Phone").Value
       Me.MailField.Value = QueryRecordset("[E-Mail]").Value
       Me!PostField.Value = QueryRecordset("EmployeePost").Value
       QueryRecordset.MoveNext
   Loop
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why are you using unbound form? Why are you looping a recordset and setting combobox RowSource?

Comment: A field is actually named "InduvialNumber" - should that have been "IndividualNumber"? Interesting that database structure appears as English but data is another language.

Comment: Value is default property of data controls. Don't have to actually show it in code.

Comment: If this is VBA then add tag.